# Is `self` actually sometimes late in PHP?

Tags: php

PHP [docs on late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) explain that `self::` resolves to the class in which the code is written and I would take away that `self::test()` should equal `CurrentClass::test()` if I'm writing that code in the class `CurrentClass`.

However, consider this PHP snippet that is quite similar to "Example #1" of that docs page:

```php
<?php

class A
{
    // Print the "static" class -- will use late binding
    public static function meth(): string
    {
        return static::class;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function check(): void
    {
        // These call `meth()` on A, B, C respectively and echoes the name
        echo "A: ".A::meth()."\n";
        echo "B: ".B::meth()."\n";
        echo "C: ".C::meth()."\n";

        // This should call `meth()` on B as it's defined in B
        echo "self: ".self::meth()."\n";

        // This should call `meth()` on whatever class we have at runtime
        echo "static: ".static::meth()."\n";

        // These should call `meth()` on B as __CLASS__ and self::class
        // are both equal to B here
        echo "__CLASS__: ".(__CLASS__)::meth()."\n";
        echo "selfclass: ".(self::class)::meth()."\n";

        // This should call `meth()` on whatever class we have at runtime
        echo "staticclass: ".(static::class)::meth()."\n";
    }
}

// In C `static` should be C, but we are not overriding `check`, so
// the `self`s should remain B.
class C extends B {}

(new C)->check();
```

Contrary to inline comments, here's what the code prints out (on PHP 8.1.2):

```bash
A: A
B: B
C: C
self: C
static: C
__CLASS__: B
selfclass: B
staticclass: C
```

While most of the output is what I expected, the line `self: C` shows that `self::meth()` has somehow printed `C`, implying the call was actually equivalent to `C::meth()` not `B::meth()`.

Is that a bug? Is that a quirk? Did I read the docs wrong? Or is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Have you noticed the difference between `self` and `static`?

Comment: @RoboRobok yes, and I expected `self::` and `static::` to call the method on different classes.

Comment: But `meth()` method uses `static`, so it's always gonna use the direct caller of the method. I understand your thinking pattern, but check out in the docs how it actually works.

Comment: No, this is not a bug, but rather the expected behavior of late static binding

Comment: @RoboRobok which page of docs do you have in mind?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto but the question is about self. If I'm typing `self::meth()` in `B`, I would expect it to do `B::meth()`. But instead it behaves more like `$this->meth()` keeping the binding to caller.

Comment: @Džuris if you call `self::meth()` from within class B, it will always refer to the `meth()` defined in class A, even if it is called on an instance of C.

Comment: when `self` is used, it always refers to the class in which it is defined, not the class of the current object

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I understand that it's calling the implementation from `A`. The question is why `self::meth()` doesn't make it a pure `B::meth()` call, but actually passes some late reference to `C` to that method?

Comment: @Džuris because `self::meth()` always resolves to the class where the method is defined, not the class where it is being called from

Comment: @WahyuKristianto that's what I expected, but `self::meth()` in `B` does not return what `B::meth()` does in this case :)